# Disable WiFi assist UDP transfer on iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, network-programming, wifi, gcdasyncudpsocket

I want to send UDP packages in a local network using GCDAsyncUdpSocket.
My fear is that at some point UDP packages will be sent via LTE because of the newly introduced "WiFi assist" from iOS 9.
Is there some way I can pretend iOS 9 from passing my traffic to cellular network, and instead require it to always use WiFi?

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49754105/730807)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "Reachability" to detect if the phone is connected to a wi-fi or to cellular data and then avoid to send message or manage the that particular condition. You can also ask to the user to disable the wi-fi assistant with a popup just to be sure to avoi the problem.