# WiFi Assist iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am working on an iOS app which communicates with some hardware on the local network via wss.

Unfortunately due to WiFi assist I frequently end up with the traffic intended for a lan IP says 192.168.0.18 being pushed onto cellular via WiFi assist.

Is there a way to stop that from happening without requiring the user to switch off WiFi assist? I seen Sonos had similar issues some time ago but do not see how they solved it.

Additionally I note the apple site explains some 3rd party apps which transfer large volumes of data or stream video will not use WiFi assist.. how are they doing that?

** This is different to that of the mobile config question already posted as this is a commercial app not on managed devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to disable wifi assist without user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754105/how-to-disable-wifi-assist-without-user-interaction)

Comment: It touches on it a little but not how Sonos fixed it or the apps Apple refer to on their explanation.